# How to add an profile field using ASP.Net membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I am working on an app using the ASP.NET membership provider. By default, i can use a few fields such as username, password. How to add to the asp.net membership provider so I can add Profile fields such as "firstName", "lastName" in the register section and have it save to the database in aspnet_profile table along with other data.

I am creating a user in the account model as below:

```
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password,
            model.Email,model.PasswordQuestion,model.PasswordAnswer,
            true, null,out createStatus);
            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Now which function i should use to store profile info into db?
Help me !!

Answer (score 3):

Add the fields to the profile section of Web.Config.

```
<profile>
 <properties>
  <add name="FirstName" />
  <add name="LastName" />
  <add name="Address1" />
  <add name="Address2" />
  <add name="City" />
  <add name="State" />
  <add name="Zip" />
  <add name="Phone" />
  <add name="ProfileVersion" type="int" defaultValue="0" />
  </properties>
 </profile>
```

For more information please visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163457.aspx